# JS : How do I get the innerHTML of a TD element when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, innerhtml

I've started to learn JavaScript not long ago.

I have several td elements in HTML and when I click on one of them, I would like to get it's innerHTML in JS. (Vanilla JS)

```
<div class="calendarCont">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Jan</td>
         <td>Feb</td>
         <td>Mar</td>
         <td>Apr</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>May</td>
         <td>Jun</td>
         <td>Jul</td>
         <td>Aug</td>
      </tr>                                                                 
   </table>
</div>
```

I already know this method :

```
<td onclick="clickedCell = this.innerHTML; console.log(clickedCell)>Jan</td>
```

But what I'm looking for is a function with an addEventListener if it is possible, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: All you need is already in your question. Wrap it in a function and use it as event handler for `.addEventListener()` (which should/could be obvious from the documentation of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest you to avoid inline event handler. You can first target all the tds using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then loop through them and attach the event using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.calendarCont table tr td');
tds.forEach(function(td){
  td.addEventListener('click', handleTDClick);
});

function handleTDClick(){
  console.log(this.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarCont">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Jan</td>
         <td>Feb</td>
         <td>Mar</td>
         <td>Apr</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>May</td>
         <td>Jun</td>
         <td>Jul</td>
         <td>Aug</td>
      </tr>                                                                 
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I will suggest you to avoid inline event handler"_ - Good, because that's the whole purpose of the question: _"But what I'm looking for is a function with an addEventListener"_

Comment: Just one thing, when I use this :

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.calendarCont table tr td');
```

It selects all td elements on my page, not only the ones contained in .calendarCont

So the way to select only the ones in .calendarCont is :

```
var selectedTableTD = document.querySelector('.conteneurTableauCalendrier')
var tds = selectedTableTD.querySelectorAll('td');
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Apollunar, *when I use this : `var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.calendarCont table tr td'); ` It selects all td elements on my page, not only the ones contained in .calendarCont* ,,,,,,,,is not right, it will surely only select the tds from table inside `.calendarCont`:)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript select an element that wraps all of the elements you want to be able to click. A good candidate for this might be the `<table>`, or maybe the `.calendarCont` element.

The reason for selecting a wrapping element is for event delegation, which means that all events that are triggered within the wrapping element will also be triggered on the wrapping element itself. So you'll only have to add a single event listener for all the elements. Though this will require some checking when the user clicks.

Add an event listener with `addEventListener` to the table element and listen for the `'click'` event. Write a function, like you already have which will handle the click.

Because every element can now be clicked inside the `<table>` element to trigger the click, you'll want to check which element has been clicked. Every fired event has an `Event` object with info about the event, which can be read from the event handler (callback function).

The `event.target` property is the element that triggered the click event. By evaluating if the target is the element that you are looking for you can control your event even better. For example, in your case, only show the `innerHTML` whenever the element is a `<td>`. Otherwise, do nothing.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

function onTableClick(event) {
  const isCell = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td';
  if (isCell) {
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
  }
}

table.addEventListener('click', onTableClick);
```

```html
<div class="calendarCont">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Jan</td>
         <td>Feb</td>
         <td>Mar</td>
         <td>Apr</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>May</td>
         <td>Jun</td>
         <td>Jul</td>
         <td>Aug</td>
      </tr>                                                                 
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, it helps a lot !

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` and loops will be your friends.

Target each element and loop through the result to `addEventListener` to each of the `td`.

```js
function alertInnerHTML(){
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}

let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
tds.forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener("click", alertInnerHTML)
});
```

```html
<div class="calendarCont">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Jan</td>
         <td>Feb</td>
         <td>Mar</td>
         <td>Apr</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>May</td>
         <td>Jun</td>
         <td>Jul</td>
         <td>Aug</td>
      </tr>                                                                 
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So one method that works well is :

```
var selectedTableTD = document.querySelector('.calendarCont')
var tds = selectedTableTD.querySelectorAll('td');

tds.forEach(function(td){
  td.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.textContent);
  });
});
```

Thank you everyone for your help.